# How can I connect to a running AWS instance when my dashboard says no instances are running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I feel like this is a beginner question, but after messing with it for days I'm completely stumped.

I set up an instance on Amazon AWS last year, and I'd like to SSH into the instance to upgrade some software. I am unable to find the original .pem file anywhere, and everything I find to try to solve the problem — including [these directions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/user-data-replace-key-pair-ec2/) — refer to selecting the running instance on my EC2 Dashboard.

However, when I log in as a root user, it shows there are no running instances. By default it comes up as N. Virginia, but when I check the other US locations none of them show any running resources. My instance's address (the link I use for mySQL and phpMyAdmin, for example) is in the form of ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com, if that makes any difference.

Any ideas on next steps? I have all the data on the running instance backed up so I can recreate things as necessary. I admit that I'm a beginner with AWS (obviously) but I super-pinky-promise to store my .pem file in a safe place next time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default it comes up as N. Virginia, but when **I check the other US**
> **locations** none of them show any running resources. My instance's
> address (the link I use for mySQL and phpMyAdmin, for example) is in
> the form of ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.**ca-central-1**.compute.amazonaws.com, if
> that makes any difference.

Your instance is running in the AWS Canada region, as indicated by the region name `ca-central-1` in the address, which is why you aren't seeing it in any US region.

Comment: Ah! Feeling particularly stupid (and US-centric) now, thinking it stood for California. I'll go read my Scott Pilgrim comics to repent...